# Grab the substring at the first specific character until another occurrence of the character

Tags: javascript

The input should have a param of `(string, character)`

The `character` occurs twice within the `string`.

If i have a string called `Saturday` and the character `a` is the point of start and end for the substring I want to get. So it should return `aturda`. Is this possible?

This shouldn't tied to only a specific string. So if I pass on the string `summer` it would still work the same and return `mm`, and for other strings that has two (2) character occurrences.

Comment: what is the expected result for `summer`?

Comment: It should be `mm`
If I pass on `digital` it should result in `igi`

Comment: Why summer should return `mm` its not between `a`?

Comment: Can you add the rules.

Comment: Just updated it. Hope it makes more sense

Comment: I have updated my answer. Can you check?

Comment: @Nabi it's still not clear. for `summer` do we need `m` as the second argument in the function?

Comment: @Nabi what happens when no 2 the same chars in a string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string by `a` or the char then remove the first and last element because when the str is splited by `a` the last and first segment is not between `a` then concat the string again and if there is not result return empty string.

```js
const Process = (str, character) => {
  const chars = str.split(character)

  chars.pop()
  chars.shift()

  return `${character}${chars.join(character)}${character}`
}

console.log(Process("Saturday", 'a'))
console.log(Process("Summer", 'm'))
console.log(Process("After", 'a'))
console.log(Process("Allow", 'a'))
console.log(Process("Digital", 'i'))
```

Comment: Your solution worked for what I intend to do and easier to understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `match()` along with the regex pattern `(\w)[^\1]*?\1`:

```js
var input = "Saturday";
var m = input.match(/(\w)[^\1]*?\1/)[0];
console.log(m);
```

The regex pattern used here says to match:

- `(\w)` any single letter (captured in `\1`)
- `[^\1]*?` followed by any letter other than `\1`, zero or more times
- `\1` followed by the nearest same initial letter

Comment: But it wouldn't work if I pass on 'Summer' as input

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what should be as the result when there's no 2 char occurences in a word. Returned `null`.
The fastest way is to use `String::indexOf` and `String::lastIndexOf`:

```js
const extract = (str, char) => {
  const from = str.indexOf(char), to = str.lastIndexOf(char);
  return from >= 0 && to >= 0 && from !== to ? str.slice(from, to) + String.fromCodePoint(str.codePointAt(to)) : null;
};

console.log(extract("Saturday", 'a'))
console.log(extract("Summer", 'm'))
console.log(extract("Smarter", 'a'))
console.log(extract("Allow", 'a'))
console.log(extract("Digital", 'i'))
console.log(extract(" calls ", ""))
```

Comment: This does not work for characters represented by [tag:surrogate-pairs]. For example, `extract(" calls ", "")` returns `' calls \ud83d'`, because the second `` is cut off after the first half of the surrogate pair.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen fixed, if you know a better way let me know